# Долгая прогрузка сайта с помощью библиотеки grab в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, grab

Очень долго(относительно) происходит вход на сайт и переход на другую страницу. Можно ли как нибудь ускорить этот процесс? В .setup использую

```
g.setup(timeout = 5000, connect_timeout = 5000)
```